# How do you copy from gitbash（Git Bash）

Tags: git-bash

I'm using git-for-windows MING64 MinTTY running on Windows 7. When I select text on git bash, it always trigger ctrl+C（which will display ^C in the next command line.

e.g.: When I left click down to select “git --version”, then left click up, the next command line becomes “$^C”.

```
$ git --version

git version 2.9.2.windows.1

$^C
```

Has anyone ever encounted this issue? And how to fix it?
I download the exe file from https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you upload a screen grab?

Comment: I'm not able to upload image directory now, can you see the "enter image description here" in the first line? Click it will see the screen grab.

Comment: Does clicking the top-left of the cmd window near the MINGW64 icon open a dropdown menu?  Or try ALT+space.

Comment: I tried the older versions, the results are same.

Comment: Yes, it opens a dropdown menu. I right click on the bar will also open this menu. In the options->Mouse , I tried the options, seems no effect.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: What do your mean "I updated my answer"?

Comment: In my answer below I added a new paragraph "There's step-by-step expanded instruction here".  It contains a link.

Comment: On the `Options` window in the new image you uploaded, you could try changing the default click target from Application to Window.  I'd probably stick to the cmd solution anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select text in git bash console (OS windows) use keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925965/how-to-select-text-in-git-bash-console-os-windows-use-keyboard)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enter the **keyboard** combination **Alt+Space Bar** to open the system menu of the command window.  Then use the select and copy options from there.

There's step-by-step expanded instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28926784/4895133).

See also [Copying and Pasting in Git Bash](https://www.udacity.com/wiki/ud775/git-bash-copy-paste).  Excerpt as follows:

> **Copying and Pasting in Git Bash**
>
> The default way to copy/paste in Git Bash is by using the menu
>   (accessed by going to the top left) to "mark" to select what you want
>   to copy and then use the menu again to paste.
>
> This gets inefficient pretty quickly, so it's a good idea to set up
>   QuickEdit mode to make copying and pasting much faster.  To do this,
>   go to `Menu->Properties` and in the `Options` tab select `QuickEdit Mode`.

[image]

Comment: I'm not running the git bash from cmd, just run the git-bash.exe. The paste is effective, my main question is when I use mouse to select test on git bash window, it always prompted ^C in git bash command line, that's painful, is there anyway can suppress this?

Comment: Your question was "How do you copy from gitbash（Git Bash)"

Comment: Ok. you're right. I upload the pic again, I only allow to upload one pic now. My git-bash dropdown menu is like the one I just uploaded(can click the  "enter image description here" to see). The pic you showed is the one for git-cmd in my environment. May be the interface changed in new version.

Comment: If run in command, it calls git-cmd.exe not git-bash.exe. git-cmd.exe in command run can work normal. Thanks for you advice.

Comment: I knew you'd get there eventually. ;-)  Glad I could help.  Please select my answer. :-)

Comment: sincerely, I'm not found how to select your answer, I just registered and really new to this, or could you show me?

Comment: Sure.  There's a 'Tick' symbol and an up arrow to the top-left of my `Answer`.  Pls click them both. :-)

Answer (score 5):

- on windows 10
- Git-bash( git version 2.14.1.windows.1)

copy: CTRL + INSERT
paste: SHIFT + INSERT

Source [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/235)

Answer (score 3):

- **Copy:**  Ctrl + (Left Click Highlight)
- **Paste:** Right Click

Answer (score 2):

I use the **mouse**:

1. mark
2. right click -> copy
3. right click -> paste

Answer (score 1):

You can use [autohotkeys](https://autohotkey.com/) to convert <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> to another shotcut you want. I use this way in my autohotkeys file:

```
^+v::^Ins
```

To me is better <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to avoid compatibility issues with vim, but if you don't use vim you can use the common way.

Another solution is use console emulators like [conemu](https://conemu.github.io/) it allows you edit all shotcuts.

Answer (score 1):

In my Git Bash, I've done `Left click down > Selected text > Left click up`.
The selected text remains selected.
`^C` doesn't appear on the console.

`^C` appears on the console only if I click `Ctrl+C`.

Your settings are different from the default settings.
Use the default [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bf39.png).
mintty version: 3.4.4 (x86_64-pc-mysys) [Windows 19042]

Answer (score -1):

some other software which intercept your signal: check your processes and try to close/kill as much as possible to see if the issue persists.
in my case its **YodaoDict.exe**