# How to copy/paste text (github's url) in Bash in Windows 10?

Tags: bash, github

I'm using Windows 10.

I can cut/copy/paste in cmd or shell but i can't do that with Bash. So, I must type url of github if I want to clone something from there

Almost of guides (Dr. Google) also say: Right click -> Properties -> Options -> tick Edit Quick Mode

But I can't do because I can't find out "Quick Edit Mode" or something like that.

Please help me.

Thanks,

[Bash's Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXwdn.png)

Comment: Atleast in putty if you just select some text, it get's auto copied to the clipboard. I am not sure if MingW works the same way then you don't need a copy/paste/edit there, just select a portion of text > (right click > paste) or just right click.

Answer (score 0):

using your keyboard, you can hold down [Shift] and then hit the [Insert] key.
[Shift]+[Insert]

EDIT: If this does not help, you may find a previous post useful: [Copy Paste in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832230/copy-paste-in-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked is for:

- desktop keyboard: [shift] + [insert] keys to paste
- laptop keyboard: [shift] + [0] keys to paste

NB: For laptops, the 0 Key at the bottom of the number pad on the upper-right corner of your keyboard will function as an Insert Key when Num Lock is turned off. That is why it is labeled with both 0 and Ins on the key itself.

Answer (score 0):

To **paste** any URL or Text in gitbash, you can use " ***windows key + v*** " and select the text you copied to paste it in bash.

You just need to turn *on the clipboard history* for this to work, which can be done in clipboard settings.

As far as copy/cut is concerned I am also searching for that.