# Pipe from clipboard in linux subsytem for windows

Tags: clipboard, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using the Linux Subsystem for Windows (LSW), `clip.exe` can be used to copy data to the windows clipboard:

```
$ clip.exe /?

CLIP

Description:
    Redirects output of command line tools to the Windows clipboard.
    This text output can then be pasted into other programs.

Parameter List:
    /?                  Displays this help message.

Examples:
    DIR | CLIP          Places a copy of the current directory
                        listing into the Windows clipboard.

    CLIP < README.TXT   Places a copy of the text from readme.txt
                        on to the Windows clipboard.
```

Is there any way to pipe **FROM** the clipboard? Examples of intended use:

```
$ paste.exe > foo.txt

$ paste.exe | tr , '\n' | clip.exe
```

Comment: Feature request: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-windows-subsystem-for-l/suggestions/37592191-paste-exe-for-copying-contents-of-windows-clipboar

Comment: Why has this not received more attention? This is a pretty glaring (and inconvenient) oversight

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Solution**

This prints the Windows' clipboard to stdout:

```bash
powershell.exe Get-Clipboard
```

---

**Examples**

```bash
$ echo "hello" | clip.exe
$ powershell.exe Get-Clipboard
hello
```

```bash
$ date +%Y-%m-%d | clip.exe
$ powershell.exe Get-Clipboard
2019-06-13
```

```bash
$ alias paste.exe='powershell.exe Get-Clipboard'
$ echo "world" | clip.exe
$ paste.exe
world
```

```bash
paste() {  # Add me to your .bashrc, perhaps.
    powershell.exe Get-Clipboard | sed 's/\r$//'
    # The `sed` will remove the unwelcome carriage-returns
}
```

source: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1069#issuecomment-391968532

Comment: Nice work @NonlinearFruit! I see that with my version of WSL/Windows, `Get-Clipboard` appends `\r\n` to the end of the content. I used the following as my alias to trim these unwanted additions: `alias paste.exe="powershell.exe Get-Clipboard | perl -p -e 's/\r\n$//'"`

Comment: seems to also add trailing line, add `;$d` to sed to fix

Comment: I would strongly suggest a different name for such a function. `paste` is an existing `POSIX` tool