# How can I select text in git bash terminal in Windows 7 without mouse?

Tags: windows, bash, git-bash

I am on Windows 7 and I have Git Bash at my disposal after installing Git for Windows.

I found mouse inconvenient to select-copy-paste in terminal window. What is the shortcut for text selection (like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> in Notepad editor)?

I have seen many irrelevant verbose replies to this question, but all, what I am looking for is just an appropriate shortcut (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> for Copy and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> for Paste).

Answer (score 2):

It is best to install a CMD enhancer like [**ConEmu**](https://conemu.github.io/).

From there, you can type "`bash`", and you will see in that Git bash session, that simple <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> are enough for copy/paste.

And for selecting the text (in a ConEmu session), <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> works too. For W7 or W10.

Comment: It's strange to me that barebone unix-like approach is so helpless w/out hacks...

Comment: @Mike That is because that unix-like approach is not effective in an emulated CMD bash session. But in a ConEmu bash session, those shortcuts are better recognized.

Comment: OK. So first I install Git for Windows. Then I install ConEmu in addition to Git for Windows?

Comment: Yes, conemu is independent from git for Windows and is an all-purpose she'll in which you can execute a git bash session.